# How to synchronize separate callbacks in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, mqtt

I'm developing a nodejs application (using express) which will service REST calls from clients via HTTP. One of the REST APIs will process a POST request which will take data from POST body and publish it via an MQTT client (started as part of the application).

A separate application which is subscribed to the topic (via an MQTT broker we both connected to) I published to will receive the message and respond by publishing a message to a topic my application's MQTT client has subscribed to (which will cause a callback to trigger in my Javascript app).

I would like to be able to return the MQTT message my application receives in the POST response my application is processing.

In regular "C language programming" terms... There is a thread handling the REST APIs and a separate thread handling receiving MQTT messages (e.g. two different sockets). I'd like to block the thread processing the POST processing thread on a semaphore until the MQTT thread can receive some data, enqueue it, and release the semaphore to unblock the POST processing thread (which would then dequeue the message and return it in the POST response).

After tinkering with various modules and Promise/Generators it isn't clear to me how to make it work...

What is the "javascript way" to do this?

TIA!

Comment: Questions about code SHOULD include your actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You don't block in node.js.  By it's very design, node.js is event-driven and all network I/O (and most file I/O) is non-blocking and asynchronous.  So, you need to coordinate multiple asynchronous operations and get notified (with some sort of event) when both have finished.

It's hard to be very specific when you didn't share any of your code, but the main tool for coordinating asynchronous operations these days is promises.  So, if you make each of your async operations return a promise that will resolve when the async operation is done or reject when the async operation encounters an error, then you can use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) with the two promises and it will tell you when both async operation have finished and offer you both results.

The general idea is this:

```
 let p1 = asyncOperation1(...);
 let p2 = asyncOperation2(...);

 Promise.all([p1, p2]).then(results => {
     // both async operations are done here
     // results[0] and results[1] contain the resolved value of each of the two promises
 }).catch(err => {
     // process error here
 });
```

For getting promises from REST operations, there are a number of different solutions varying from manually doing your own promise wrapper around your operations, to modules that wrap the request module to offer promises to libraries like Bluebird that have `.promisify()` and `.promisifyAll()` methods to automatically wrap operations for you.  To offer more specific info on how to get promises out of your async operations, you would have to share you actual code.

---

Since it looks like you're new here, let me offer some posting advice.  If you show us your code, we will ALWAYS be able to offer more complete and more relevant answers.  When you don't show us your code, you're essentially asking for a general purpose tutorial which a lot harder to write and a lot harder to make sure it covers your exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

Don't block, include a unique id in the message you publish and have the response message also include this id.

You then store the express response object in an object using this id as a key so when the response arrives you and send back the response.

You should also include a timestamp so you can walk  the waiting response objects regularly and respond if the MQTT message doesn't arrive in time.

```
var onGoingRequests = {};
var id = 0;
var timeout = 3000;

mqttClient.on('message',function(topic,message){
  var payload = JSON.parse(message.toString());
  var details = onGoingRequest[payload.id];
  if (details) {
    details.response.status(200).send(details.body);
    delete onGoingRequests[payload.id];
  } else {
    //response too late
  }
});

app.post('/foo', function(req, resp) {
    var message = {
      id: 'foo' +id++,
      body: req.body
    }
    var topic = 'request/foo'; 
    mqttClient.publish(topic, JSON.stringify(message));
    onGoingRequests[message.id] = {
      response: resp,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
    }; 
});

var timeout = setInterval(function(){
  var now = Date.now();
  var keys = Object.keys(onGoingCommands);
  for (key in keys){
    var waiting = onGoingCommands[keys[key]];
    if (waiting) {
      var diff = now - waiting.timestamp;
      if (diff < timeout) {
        waiting.res.status(504).send('{"error": "timeout"}');
        delete onGoingCommands[keys[key]];
      }
    }
  }
}, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

Eventually figured out I may have been over thinking the solution...

In the POST processing callback I enqueue the response object and return. Later, in the MQTT subscribe message processing callback I dequeue the pending response object and use it to send the proper response to the pending POST transaction.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```html
import * as MQTT from 'async-mqtt';
import { Semaphore } from 'async-mutex';


@Controller()
export class AppController {
  private semaphore = new Semaphore(1);

  private mqttClient: MQTT.AsyncMqttClient;

  constructor(private readonly logger: Logger) {
    this.mqttClient = MQTT.connect('mqtt://localhost:1883');

    this.mqttClient.on('connect', () => {
      this.mqttClient.subscribe('supcon').then(() => {
        this.logger.debug('成功订阅主题 「supcon」');
      }).catch(reasone => {
        this.logger.debug('订阅主题 「supcon」失败：', reasone);
      });
    });
  }

  @Get('/')
  @UseInterceptors(ResponseInterceptor)
  async hello() {
    const [, releaseSemaphore] = await this.semaphore.acquire();

    setTimeout(() => releaseSemaphore(), 2000);
    let recvMsg;
    this.mqttClient.on('message', (topic, message) => {
      this.logger.debug(topic, message.toString());
      this.semaphore.runExclusive(() => { Promise.resolve('10') });
      recvMsg = message.toString();
      releaseSemaphore();
    });

    await this.mqttClient.publish('supcon.monitor.writetag', 'hello from nestjs');
    await this.semaphore.waitForUnlock();

    return recvMsg;
  }
 }
```